# Delete Jar Shortcut With Java File Method

Tags: java

How to delete shortcut file. Probably because i don't put the extension file name. I tried with txt file it can delete. But with shortcut it didn't. Dose shortcut have any special extension?

```
File file = new File("C://app"); //app is the shortcut
file.delete(); // when the code is executed the app shortcut file did not deleted..
```

**Solution**

```
 File file = new File("C://app.lnk"); //add .lnk (window shortcut extension)
 file.delete(); //now can delete shortcut
```

Comment: ok now i find the solution, i have to add .lnk extension for shortcut file

Comment: answer your own question and mark it as answered then

Comment: i would rather suggest to delete the question, if you are fine to not storing in the SO repository for future reference, as the need wont arise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just have to put .lnk extension to the file as below.

```
File file = new File("C://app.lnk"); //add .lnk (window shortcut extension)
file.delete(); //now can delete shortcut
```